# Document mode IE7 standards for IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, ie8-browser-mode

My document looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
        <![endif]-->
```

I'm using IE10 to test everything. When I switch Browser Mode to IE7 the Page Default Document Mode shows to be IE7 standards. However when I switch to IE8 Browser Mode the Page Default Document Mode is IE8 standards. Why doesn't the meta tag change it to IE7 standards? Is it something to do with my browser configuration? How can I make sure that everyone who look at my site from IE8 get the Document Mode of IE7 by default?

Comment: You mean you're doing it from inside IE10?

Comment: Yes, I'm using IE10 developer tools to switch between browser modes.

Answer (score 2):

You're hiding the `meta` tag, so IE10 will never see it. You'll need to remove the conditional comment wrapping.

And then, I presume that when you put IE in IE8 browser mode, that action forces use of the IE8 renderer and thus it will ignore the X-UA-Compatible header.

Comment: But wouldn't that force IE7 mode in IE9 and 10 as well?

Comment: Isn't that what you're wanting? Or are you in the situation where for some reason you want IE7 to use IE7, IE8 to use IE7, IE9 to use IE9 and IE10 to use IE10?

Comment: Exactly. I'm using a javascript plugin to do border-radius for IE8 and 7. That plugin only works for IE7 so IE8 needs to be in 7 mode. In 9 and 10 everything works as-is so they don't need to be set to lower mode.

Comment: @user1340531: I can't see that you need to do anything, then. If a user has switched IE10 to IE8 mode, they've overridden it so you can't help it. Other than by either dropping the border-radius or using a trick that works in IE8.